# a word for 'blbbhlbl'

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

is there a word for the sound made at 2:19 of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5Zo0mUO-GE&t=2m19s) video?
An interjection will also do

Comment: Trigger warning: If you're a person who hates self-important vloggers with a passion, do not click that link.

Comment: Similar to [*blowing a raspberry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_a_raspberry) but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it ***spluttering***. From *Oxford Dictionaries Online*...

> [**Splutter**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/splutter) - *Make a series of short **explosive spitting** or choking sounds*